# TicTacToe error

Tags: java, oop, tic-tac-toe

I have designed a simple tic tac toe game and here are some of my concerns:

It seems to me that the play() method does not belong in Game(). It looks better if defined in Player, but I don't know how to make it work in Player. Also, I am initializing the players by passing them an id. This looks wrong to me. How to fix this?

```
/*Game class-establishes rules and determines winner */
package game.tictactoe;

public class Game {
String[] gameState = new String[9];
Player player1;
Player player2;

// updates the gamestate array with the latest move

public void updateStatus(int position, String symbol) {
    gameState[position] = symbol;    
}

public Game() {
    player1 = new Player(1);
    player2 = new Player(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        gameState[i] = "";
    }
}

// checks if game over. If game over, return winner or tie, else return "Game in prgress"

public String getGameStatus() {
    if((gameState[0].equals(gameState[1]))
       && gameState[0].equals(gameState[2])
       && gameState[1].equals(gameState[2])
       && !gameState[0].equals("")){
        return gameState[0];
    }
    else if((gameState[3].equals(gameState[4]))
       && gameState[3].equals(gameState[5])
       && gameState[4].equals(gameState[5])
       && !gameState[3].equals("")){
        return gameState[3];
    }
    else if((gameState[6].equals(gameState[7]))
       && gameState[6].equals(gameState[8])
       && gameState[7].equals(gameState[8])
       && !gameState[6].equals("")){
        return gameState[6];
    }
    else if((gameState[0].equals(gameState[3]))
       && gameState[0].equals(gameState[6])
       && gameState[3].equals(gameState[6])
       && !gameState[0].equals("")){
        return gameState[0];
    }
    else if((gameState[1].equals(gameState[4]))
       && gameState[1].equals(gameState[7])
       && gameState[4].equals(gameState[7])
       && !gameState[1].equals("")){
        return gameState[1];
    }
    else if((gameState[2].equals(gameState[5]))
       && gameState[2].equals(gameState[8])
       && gameState[5].equals(gameState[8])
       && !gameState[2].equals("")){
        return gameState[2];
    }
    else if((gameState[0].equals(gameState[4]))
       && gameState[0].equals(gameState[8])
       && gameState[4].equals(gameState[8])
       && !gameState[0].equals("")){
        return gameState[0];
    }
    else if((gameState[2].equals(gameState[4]))
       && gameState[2].equals(gameState[6])
       && gameState[4].equals(gameState[6])
       && !gameState[2].equals("")){
        return gameState[2];
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(gameState[i].equals("")) {
                return "Game in progress";
            }
        }
        return "It's a tie!!";
    }
}

public String play(int position) {
    if(!player1.hasPlayed()) {
        player1.played(true);
        player2.played(false);
        updateStatus(position,player1.getSymbol());
        return player1.getSymbol();
    }
    else {
        player2.played(true);
        player1.played(false);
        updateStatus(position,player2.getSymbol());
        return player2.getSymbol();
    }
  }
}
/*Player class- Initializes the players that are in the game */
package game.tictactoe;  

public class Player {  
private boolean hasPlayed;  
private String symbol;  
private int id;  

Player(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
    if(id == 1) {  
        hasPlayed = false;  
       symbol = Symbols.X.toString();  
    }  
    else {  
        hasPlayed = true;  
        symbol = Symbols.O.toString();  
    }  
}  

public void played(boolean flag) {  
    hasPlayed = flag;  
}  
public boolean hasPlayed() {  
     return hasPlayed;   
}  
public String getSymbol() {  
    return symbol;  
}  
} 
/* Symbol-Enum that represents the two symbols used in the game */
package game.tictactoe;  

public enum Symbols {  
X,O;  
}
```

Comment: That logic can greatly be improved upon by the way. It could all be done with some simple algorithms. Another thing, if a equals b and a equals c, c equals b has to be true.

Comment: Why do you think `play()` doesn't belong in `Game`? Something has to coordinate players taking turns.  Maybe renaming `Game` to `GameController` would ease your qualms.

Comment: ...or perhaps having a `GameContoller` class that `Game` *has* in some fashion, then all games *are* `Game`s which *have* `Player`s etc. `TicTacToe` *is* of course a `Game`.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to approach a programming solution from the Object-Oriented perspective is to begin by asking yourself "what are all the nouns in my application space?"

As we've learned from 1970's era Saturday morning television, a noun is a person, place, or thing.

Enumerating all the nouns in your application should become the basis for all the classes that you'll want to write for your application.  Nouns are the objects.  And so, the objects you need to use will each need a class written for them.

In Tic Tac Toe, the nouns could be: Game, Grid, Symbol, Player

After you've enumerated the nouns in your application, you can often next think about the behaviors that are associated with them.  Ask yourself "what behaviors do my nouns have?" or "what actions are performed on my nouns?"  This should become the basis for the methods that you write.  The methods you write should naturally be written for the classes that they act upon.

For example, a Grid can have a mark placed into it.  A Grid can also be checked to see if a Player has won.  A Player can make his move.  You can anticipate the methods you'll want to write for your classes by asking yourself questions like this.

Another thing to ask yourself is "what characteristics (or attributes) do my nouns have?"  A Game, for example, can have a count of games played.  A Player can have a count of wins and losses.  These characteristics have a "has a" relationship with their nouns, an important clue that they should become the instance fields for your classes.

I would say that you're on the right track, but you have not gone far enough to maximize the object orientation of your application.  It is still too procedural.  For that reason, you can anticipate that it will be brittle, i.e. hard to modify if you want to make changes without breaking your app.  Predicating your design upon a solid foundation of objects will help you break your application into small, manageable, and more robustly maintainable pieces.